# Finding index by iterating each element of a vector over each row of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an numpy array 'A' of size `5000x10`. I also have another vector `'B'` of size 5000x1. I want to apply the following to each row of A:

```
import numpy as np
np.max(np.where(B[0] > A[0,:]))
```

i.e. each row of B should be tested to corresponding row of A.

Is there a pythonic way than writing a for loop for above?